# How can I center two stacked icons vertically and horizontally in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I'm trying to learn me some flutter and I have got stuck on a "little" thing while trying to make my first app.

I want to use two Icons together (stacked and centered with their middle over one another) to get a new symbol and thought it was just to stack them and center them, but every time I try something different it looks about the same with the two icons aligned to the top-left corner.

This is my code which obviously doesn't get me the result I want:

```
  Marker toStackedIconsMarker() {
    return Marker(
        point: LatLng(mapPosition.latitude, mapPosition.longitude),
        builder: (context) => SizedBox(
              child: Center(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.circle_outlined, size: 50, color: Colors.white),
                    Icon(Icons.radio_button_checked,
                        size: 10, color: Colors.white),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }
```

Anyone out there with any ideas.
Would be mighty thankful!
Cheers!

Comment: Actually I got it to look ok by using alignment: Alignment.bottomRight. Don't know why yet..

Comment: I you have a "cleaner" way of solving this I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about the design I am sharing a code in which
circles are stacked left to right  play with the position parameter I
hope you will get what you are trying to do

```
  SizedBox(
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 0,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569- 
 6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb- 




    1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZmlsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw
         %3D&w=1000&q=80',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 75,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/side-view-of-one- 
         young-woman-picture-id1134378235? 

          k=20&m=1134378235&s=612x612&w=0&h=
         0yIqc847atslcQvC3sdYE6bRByfjNTfOkyJc5e34kgU=',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 150,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529665253569- 
       6d01c0eaf7b6?ixlib=rb- 


      1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZmlsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw
      %3D&w=1000&q=80',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        left: 225,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/side-view-of-one- 
         young-woman-picture-id1134378235? 
             k=20&m=1134378235&s=612x612&w=0&h=0yIqc847ats
           lcQvC3sdYE6bRByfjNTfOkyJc5e34kgU=',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I finally solved it.. only to create my own Icon for the job.